# xmlstarlet match/parsing by attribute instead of element

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I have a complex structured XML file from which I'm trying to parse some values, using xmlstartlet.  I think the issue is that the logical objects are identified by element attributes and not the actual element names.

The file test.xml, simplified for this example, looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configDump>
  <cluster top-level-assembly="XYZ12312312312">
  </cluster>
  <views>
    <view status="ok" name="ABC">
      <viewInitiators>
        <viewInitiator id="ABCi1"></viewInitiator>
        <viewInitiator id="ABCi2"></viewInitiator>
      </viewInitiators>
      <viewPorts>
        <viewPort id="ABCp1"></viewPort>
        <viewPort id="ABCp2"></viewPort>
      </viewPorts>
      <viewVolumes>
        <viewVolume lun="1" id="ABCv1"></viewVolume>
        <viewVolume lun="2" id="ABCv2"></viewVolume>
      </viewVolumes>
    </view>
    <view status="ok" name="DEF">
      <viewInitiators>
        <viewInitiator id="DEFi1"></viewInitiator>
        <viewInitiator id="DEFi2"></viewInitiator>
      </viewInitiators>
      <viewPorts>
        <viewPort id="DEFp1"></viewPort>
        <viewPort id="DEFp2"></viewPort>
      </viewPorts>
      <viewVolumes>
        <viewVolume lun="1" id="DEFv1"></viewVolume>
        <viewVolume lun="2" id="DEFv2"></viewVolume>
      </viewVolumes>
    </view>
  </views>
</configDump>
```

I'm trying to generate output with fields that look like:

```
<top-level-assembly>-<view-name>,<viewInitiator-ID>
```

When I run the following:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t \
                -m //cluster \
                        --var sn=@top-level-assembly \
                -m //views/view \
                        --var view=@name \
                -m //views/view/viewInitiators/viewInitiator \
                        -v 'concat($sn,"-",$view,",",@id)' -n test.xml
```

I get the following output:

```
XYZ12312312312-ABC,ABCi1
XYZ12312312312-ABC,ABCi2
XYZ12312312312-ABC,DEFi1
XYZ12312312312-ABC,DEFi2
XYZ12312312312-DEF,ABCi1
XYZ12312312312-DEF,ABCi2
XYZ12312312312-DEF,DEFi1
XYZ12312312312-DEF,DEFi2
```

As you can seem I am getting all the "initiator" values under each "view", and not just the ones that are in that structure in the XML.  I was expecting and hoping to get just:

```
XYZ12312312312-ABC,ABCi1
XYZ12312312312-ABC,ABCi2
XYZ12312312312-DEF,DEFi1
XYZ12312312312-DEF,DEFi2
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

The `-m` options nest - to `xsl:for-each` statements - so you're asking for all `viewInitiator/@id`s for each `view`. To see the generated XSLT code add a `-C` option before `-t`.

The desired output can be generated by:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t \
    --var sn='configDump/cluster/@top-level-assembly' \
    -m '//viewInitiator' \
       -v 'concat($sn,"-",../../@name,",",@id)' -n \
< file.xml
```

Comment: Thanks!  It's actually "../../@name" in that final line, but I got the gist!  I'm an XML newbie, and the xmlstarlet documentation isn't so great (I think it assumes you have some knowledge but doesn't tell you where to get it if you don't), so I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Noso Opforu: You're not the first to scratch your head over [tag:xmlstarlet] documentation. Thanks for the heads-up on the missing `../`; it's fixed now.